# python - Importing a file that is a symbolic link

Tags: python, testing, import

If I have files x.py and y.py . And y.py is the link(symbolic or hard) of x.py .

If I import both the modules in my script. Will it import it once or it assumes both are different files and import it twice.

What it does exactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python will import it twice.

A link is a file system concept. To the Python interpreter, `x.py` and `y.py` are two different modules.

```
$ echo print \"importing \" + __file__ > x.py
$ ln -s x.py y.py
$ python -c "import x; import y"
importing x.py
importing y.py
$ python -c "import x; import y"
importing x.pyc
importing y.pyc
$ ls -F *.py *.pyc
x.py  x.pyc  y.py@  y.pyc
```

Answer (score 13):

You only have to be careful in the case where your script itself is a symbolic link, in which case the first entry of sys.path will be the directory containing the target of the link.

Comment: Ah, yes, I just ran into that. I'm pointing to a script in my 'deployment' area, which during development is a symlink to the original copy that I'm editing. Took me a long time to figure out why python couldn't find other modules that are sitting right there in the same directly where the symlink exists. Rather annoying, actually.